# Best practices for creating mongodb collection keeping hard disc storage in mind

Tags: mongodb, datastore

I am new to mongodb and want to know about best practices to follow before creating any collection keeping hard disk storage in mind. Example - I have a collection named "users" which stores following keys for documents, Either I can store data like

```
users: {name: "abc", address: "xyz", isActive: true}
```

or

```
users: {n: "abc", add: "xyz", isa: true}
```

basically storing alias in second case.

My questions are:

1. Will storing alias helps in minimising hard disk storage of database?, if yes then how?
2. Will data type of isActive (or isa) affect hard disk storage of database, so that I can choose string or int to store isActive information if bool is taking more size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, use alias will help minimising database size.

you can see this very easily:

```
> db.lg.insert({name: "abc", address: "xyz", isActive: true})
> db.sm.insert({n: "abc", add: "xyz", isa: true})
> db.lg.stats()
{
"ns" : "test.lg",
"size" : 64,
"count" : 1,
"avgObjSize" : 64,
"storageSize" : 16384,
 ... }
> db.sm.stats()
"ns" : "test.sm",
"size" : 52,
"count" : 1,
"avgObjSize" : 52,
"storageSize" : 4096,
... }
```

As you can see, document with alias are 12 bits smaller than documents with full key.

2. Of course, data type will affect storage type. MongoDB use [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) to store the data.

for example :

- store isa as boolean: `{isa: true}` document size = 28 bits
- store isa as string: `{isa: "true"}`  document size = 36 bits
- store isa as double: `{isa: 1 }`    document size = 35 bits

list of data type size is available here http://bsonspec.org/spec.html